# Does a current KMS need old versions' keys?

Tags: windows, kms

When installing the Volume Activation role on Windows Server 2012 R2 and activating it with a Server 2012 Std/Datacenter KMS host key, would I still need to install the older product versions' keys (Server 2008 - Server 2012) to get the Vista+ and Server 2008+  instances activated?

The same question goes for Office 2013 - will an Office Pro Plus 2013 key activate Office Pro Plus 2010 as well?

Our "old" Server 2008R2-based KMS server which is due to be phased out is listing a plethora of keys as the output of `slmgr.vbs /dlv /all`, most of them with `License Status: Unlicensed`, but I simply do not know if this means they are never ever used again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Windows KMS the newer key will activate down-level clients. See section [1.2 Plan for Key Management Services activation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/JJ134256.aspx) for a nice table. The product key group "Volume license for Windows Server 2012 R2" can activate the following versions:

- Windows Server 2012 R2 (all editions)
- Windows 8.1 Enterprise
- Windows 8.1 Pro
- Windows Server 2012 (all editions)
- Windows 8 Professional
- Windows 8 Enterprise
- Windows 2008 (all editions)
- Windows 2008 R2 (all editions)
- Windows 7 Professional
- Windows 7 Enterprise
- Windows Vista Business
- Windows Vista Enterprise

The same is not true for Office KMS. You must install both Office 2010 and 2013 KMS Host License Packs on the same KMS server. Please see [How to setup and install an Office 2010 and 2013 KMS Host](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2852521)

Comment: Thanks, the MSKB 2852521 for Office activation was especially helpful as I have not been able to find a reference to the "Office 2010 KMS Host License Pack" download before. The Office 2010 KMS key is rejected as invalid unless the License Pack is installed.